# Raphaeljs charts bar index fetching

Tags: raphael

Is there a way to get a bar's index value?

So for example

```
bar_chart.hover(function() { 
        var test = this.bar.index; 
});
```

Or something to that effect? Basically, if the bar chart consists of 10 colums and I click on the third, I would want the value 3 returned.

Thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 1):

First assign an index to each bar, by adding an attribute called "index" to it:

```
(function() {
    var i = 0;
    bar_chart.each(function(one_bar) { 
        one_bar.index = i++;
    });
})();
```

Then you can use exactly the syntax you suggested:

```
bar_chart.hover(function() { 
        var test = this.bar.index; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bosh almost got it. This code worked for me:

```
    var i = barchart.bars.length;
    barchart.each(function() {
        this.bar.index = --i;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

or -

```
 for (i = 0; i < iMax; i++) {
  chart.bars[0][i].myIndex = i;
 }
```