# Raphael bar chart - bc.bars.length always returning 1

Tags: raphael, graphael

Hi I am using Raphael to generate a bar chart on my web and would like to attach an index to the bars following the replies in this page

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057035/raphaeljs-charts-bar-index-fetching?answertab=votes#tab-top.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679785/graphael-bar-chart-with-text-x-axis)

In order to do this, I will need to fetch the value of bc.bars.length. However, no matter how many bars are in my bar chart, bc.bars.length always returning 1.

Here is my code:

```
//Create a bar chart using the values in the selected objects
r = Raphael("bar");
txtattr = { font: "12px arial" };
r.text(160, 10, "Title").attr(txtattr);

var bc = r.barchart(10, 10, 300, 220, [myData]).hover(fin, fout);
alert(bc.bars.length); //always returning 1
```

Anyone knows what is going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this might be a little late, but for anyone out there, you know, I found myself in the same situation, so let me share my answer and the things I noticed:

(I'm using graphael 0.5.1)

-I noticed that when you use and array for the bars, it returns 1, like what you have:

```
var bc = r.barchart(10, 10, 300, 220, [myData])
alert(bc.bars.length); //always returning 1
```

-BUT if you put the values directly, like:

```
var bc = r.barchart(10, 10, 300, 220, [100,450,340,500])
alert(bc.bars.length); //seems to return 4
```

-BUT ! that doesn't work if you are getting dinamic data!

so THE SOLUTION I'VE FOUND IS THIS:

```
//after creating the barchart, let's loop it
var i = 1;
bc.each(function() { 
      i++;
  console.log("bar: "+ i);
});
var total_bars=i-1;
console.log('total_bars: '+total_bars)
```

I hope this helps other people =), this is a nice library to chart, but it's a shame it's a little buggy with each new version, like the labels and such =(